# Properly configuring a dotnet (ASP.NET Core 2.1) environment on CentOS / Linux

Tags: c#, linux, apache, asp.net-core, centos7

I'm stuck, I'm really hoping someone can help or at least point me in the right direction. My end goal is to get my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app running on a CentOS Linux box. Since I'm using a mongo db in my actual app and wanted to eliminate any possible issues with that, I published a plain-jane asp.net core 2.1 mvc app, no authentication, and deployed it to a virtual host on my centos 7 box (apache upgraded via CoreIT to 2.4.37 since centos distros still deploy the older 2.4.6 version).

For the scope of this question I think I just need to make sure my reverse proxy is working properly and need help in pinning down that. I've followed instructions from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) and the Microsoft setup doc from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1). These 2 links are what I've been working with mainly.

When my app service is running, I can do a curl localhost:5000 and see the correct html of my homepage being returned. When I try from command line again with test.mydomain.com or test.mydomain.com:5000 it just times out. If I go to my app's conf (test.mydomain.com.conf in /etc/httpd/sites-available) and remove the ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse and ProxyPreserveHost lines then I can hit test.mydomain.com from the outside with a browser and get my index.html file up and displaying properly (this is just one index.html file and not a part of the dotnet app though). It's only when I add the below back into my conf file it just hangs up when I try and hit the URL. I'm not sure what to look for in journalctl or maybe I should tail a specific log file to find out what it's waiting on and why it's taking so long.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Somehow is seems like my reverse proxy isn't set up right to be accessed from outside the box.

The rest of my app's config below.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.mydomain.com/public_html
    ErrorLog logs/dashboard.crtv1.com.errorlog
    CustomLog logs/dashboard.crtv1.com.access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I addressed the issue although I'm not sure what issues I was actually having at the time of posting. I ended up through process of elimination and curl to find another service was running and using port 5000 in another virtual host - we're doing development and need a test, staging and production set of virtual hosts. Also I found I had some code in my app (UseUrls) that was specifically stating to use port 5000 so multiple copies of it within the same environment had resource conflicts. I'll circle back and update which environments will use which ports and hopefully have a nice set up.